# Open Word document in Browser

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have created some document templates for Word, Excel and PowerPoint in office 365 sharepoint online and I have saved them on my desktop, I have created 3 content types as well and each content type is using associated template. I Can see all 3 options when I click on "New" button in document library. When I click on new "word" document, my installed word application is launched.

Can I open new word document in office web app in browser?
All templates are developed in office web app and I have downloaded them on my desktop.
I have tried all 3 options in document library to open document in browser but still unable to open document in browser.

Comment: I did same but when i open from Dynamics 365 CRM this change is not reflecting.

Answer (score 3):

- Can you verify what is the default behaviour of **Opening Documents** in the library settings>Advanced?

[image]

- Another possibility is a site collection feature. Go to Site settings>Site collection features> Open Documents in Client Applications by Default
  The feature should be deactivated

[image]

- Verify if the issue is browser related. Do you get the same behaviour in all browsers? If not, please go to the Internet Options in your web browser, select the add-on "SharePoint Open Documents Class" and disable it:

Comment: That feature is already de actiavted and in document settings 3rd option is checked, Allow management of content types is checked and I have my own custom content types, each content type has a template but I am unable to open in browser.

Comment: I just tried on 2 more computer, one had office 2013 installed and second without any office product installed.

both produced different results, the system which has office installed is opening all docs in office application and other system is opening everything in browser which is what I want, Is there any other settings I need to do? I believe settings in document library to open everything in browser has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

you want to open your document templates for Word, Excel and PowerPoint in office 365 share point online then click an HTML link to a Microsoft Office file (such as a Microsoft Word or Excel document), Internet Explorer may open the file in Internet Explorer, instead of opening the file in the appropriate Office program.

Comment: This seems to be a partial answer taken from [Microsoft's support](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/162059)

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue. Fixed by disabling the **32-bit version of SharePoint OpenDocument Class from Manage Add-ons** in Internet Explorer.