# SharePoint 2016 On Premise - Force MS Office documents to open in browser

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, download, browsers

I know this sounds a repeating question to [Open Word document in Browser](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133475/open-word-document-in-browser)

However i have tried all the options mentioned therein. Unfortunately non of them are working. Document download to client computer.

Ours is SharePoint 2016 On Premise environment. My computer has MS Office 2016.

How do we Force MS Office documents to open in browser.

Kindly advise what i am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have **Office Online Server for SharePoint 2016** installed to be able to open and edit your files in browser.

Office Online Server is the successor to Office Web Apps Server. 
please find the below link for how to install  configure Office Online Server. 
[Configure Office Online Server for SharePoint Server 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/configure-office-online-server-for-sharepoint-server-2016/configure-office-online-server-for-sharepoint-server-2016) 

[How to Install Office Online Server for SharePoint 2016](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e10903f-9311-4926-8bbb-89a275f5ded1/how-to-install-office-online-server-for-sharepoint-2016?forum=SP2016)

Comment: Thanks Saeed for the response and answer. Is there are way to make Files open in Read Only mode in OOS...