# SharePoint 2016 On Premises - Forcefully download document on Local System

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-on-prem, download

I know this is a repeating question, I see this block [SharePoint 2016 On-Premise - Force MS Office documents to open in browser](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/238574/sharepoint-2016-on-premise-force-ms-office-documents-to-open-in-browser).

But my requirement is little bit different. I have created a custom page, where I have added a link to download document(download the document on the local system).

In Chrome, Firefox it is working as expected, but in IE browser it will open in word directly from the SharePoint site and also able to save back to the SharePoint site. For security purpose, I want to restrict to open in word.

In short, I wanted to always download the document on the local system. The user who download this document, will not be able to save document back into the SharePoint site.

FYI - I don't want to configure Office Online Server.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a single document, you could always create a link that forces a download by adding to a normal anchor tag.

By using `/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=` you can target a single existing file in SharePoint that make's a one-click download locally easy.

Note that the hive-folder is different depending on your version. 15 is for 2013, 14 for 2010 and 16 for 2016.

```
<a href='https://sharepointUrl/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=https://sharepointUrl/sites/example/documents/document.docx'>Download File</a>
```

Works in IE.